# Pre load content with jquery with .scroll before user gets to bottom of page at 50% (middle) of page

Tags: jquery

I have a [site you can see the example](http://www.flixnetforme.com/) where when you scroll to the bottom of the page, it will propagate more content. I have it setup to show 36 records at a time, so when the user hits the bottom of the page it loads the next 36 records (continuous scrolling).

What I have noticed is that when I scroll while using a desktop computer there is almost no lag at all. It loads pretty fast. When I scroll with a phone there is a lag to the point that the user "might" think they are at the bottom of the page and not want to keep on scrolling.

My idea is that I would like to be able to load the next set of content (36 records) when the user hits the middle of the page instead of waiting till they hit the bottom of the page. The reasoning (in my mind) is that this gives (slower devices and bandwidth) time to load the content ahead of time to compensate for the lag.

Is there a way to specify in jquery to load the content with `.scroll` at 50% of the page instead of waiting till the user hits the bottom?

Here is my jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if ($("#genres").val() == 'moviesidontlike') {
            last_id = $(".getmoremovies:last").attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/getmoredontlike.php?",
                data: "last_id="+ last_id,
                success: function(data) {
                    $( ".append" ).append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else if ($("#genres").val() == 'moviesilike') {
            last_id = $(".getmoremovies:last").attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/getmorelike.php?",
                data: "last_id="+ last_id,
                success: function(data) {
                    $( ".append" ).append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else if ($("#genres").val() == 'recommendations') {
        } else {
            last_id = $(".getmoremovies:last").attr("id");
            thissearch = $('#search').val();
            genres = $("#genres").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/getmore.php?",
                data: "last_id="+ last_id+
                "&genres="+ genres+
                "&search="+ thissearch,
                success: function(data) {
                    $( ".append" ).append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
$(window).on('scroll load', function() { // adding load event to handle it in case of default scroll done on page load
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop(),
        docHeight = $(document).height(),
        windHeight = $(this).height();
    var scrollPercent = ((scrolled  / (docHeight  - windHeight )) * 100).toFixed(2);
    if (scrollPercent >= 50) {
        //load more stuff...
    }
});
```

That's said, scroll event can be called multiple times in a row, you should debounce it a little surely, using a timeout.

One more thing, if when adding content following your ajax request the scroll percentage is still over 50%, it will load more stuff again and again. This logic could be harder to handle obviously...

Comment: I am marking this as a solution to my question because it does exactly what I asked and quite nicely. Problem (as @A. Wolff) pointed out it practically keeps loading. I ended up redesigning my site to work a different way, but as I said this code does work pretty nice.